# Creating percentage heights for divs in a 100% width container

Tags: css

I am creating a website that consists of an image with certain areas that are links.  I want the image to be `width: 100%`, and the `height` to be `auto`, in order to keep the aspect ratio.

All of the places in the image that I want to be links would be scaled as well, so I was thinking of creating divs with percentage margins to create scale-able areas.  This is working for the width of the divs,

The problem is that the `height`  from the elements are not well controlled and don't seem to honor the height I set.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work, or a suggestion for a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you link up a wee demo on jsbin or something?

Comment: All of the places in the image that I want to be links would be scaled as well, - not clear

Comment: as @ArleyM pointed out, it is always a good idea to include a short demo showing your problems when it is web related. welcome to stack overflow by the way.

Comment: Ok I will try to give some examples!  Here is an image showing the basic layout I want http://i.imgur.com/TPce5Uz.jpg.  I want to make it so you click on the red box to go to the first link, the green box to go to the second link, and the orange box to go to the third link.  I want the whole image to fill the width of your monitor, and these boxes to scale accordingly.  What I've been trying to do is create divs over these boxes that scale because they are positioned using percentage margins and percentage width and height.

Comment: Here is an example where I try to create colored div boxes.  When I scale the image by changing the size of the browser window, the div box heights don't scale properly. http://jsbin.com/oqojef/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways I can think of. The one that wouldn't need any additional markup would be to put `position: relative` on the `#bigbox`. Then you can position the small boxes absolutely with top and bottom values rather than a height value.

CSS:

```
img{
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;    
}

div#bigbox {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div#smallbox1 {
  left: 11%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  bottom: 23%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: red;  
}

div#smallbox2 {
  margin-left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  width:20%;
  bottom: 23%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Update to your jsbin here: [jsbin.com/oqojef/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/oqojef/2/edit)